# Extend Object Class and manage directly the events is a good pratice?

Tags: java, android, class, object, optimization

In my project i have extended some classes, for example the Button Class, and have managed some events in the extended class. Here is the code:

```
public class MySpecificButton extends Button{
public MySpecificButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    onButtonClick();
}

public MySpecificButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    onButtonClick();
}

public MySpecificButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    onButtonClick();
}

public void onButtonClick() {
    this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getContext();
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View addGameDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_console, null);
            final AlertDialog addGameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

            addGameDialog.setView(addGameDialogView);
            ListView listView = (ListView)addGameDialogView.findViewById(R.id.lstView_AllConsole);
            String[] arrayList = {"Playstation 1", "Playstation 2","Playstation 3", "Playstation 4","Playstation Portable", "Playstation Vita","Xbox", "Xbox 360","Xbox One", "Wii","Wii U", "Ds","3DS"
                    , "Skyrim"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            addGameDialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_closeAddConsole).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    addGameDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            addGameDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

And in the XML file have added this:

```
<mygames.mygamesapp.eu.myapplication.ExtendedClasses.MySpecificButton
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_addConsole"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp" />
```

I do this only for the objects that require a lot of code, so that the MainActivity class is simpler to read and manage. I would know if this is a good pratice.. Thanks

Comment: how does this work? it seems `onButtonClick()` sets the listener, but never fires it.

Comment: It works, it is called with the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Button is a view ; do not use it as controller or model ~
in your code, you let button do too much work~
nobody use it like this.